# Using TF to detect user

Tags: openi-tracker, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the TF transforms from Openni_tracker to detect the presence of a person. I want to perform an action when a "user" is detected.

Is this possible - I'm aware that openni_tracker publishes "New User" and "Pose Psi" detected but this isn't published to a topic so I'm not sure if it is possible to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167796/using-tf-to-detect-user/) by [rmb209](https://answers.ros.org/users/14126/rmb209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_tracker publishes only the the set of transforms for the skeleton joints for each tracked users.
You can look for all or one of these (i.e. head_1 or head_2).
However, you can also modify the code in order to add a topic for the "New User", but, as far as I understood, when the program says "New user detected", you do not have the tracked skeleton necessarily.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1